# Transforming DataFrame to dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

df:

```
Employee Day Hours_Worked
Tom      Monday  5
John     Monday  2 
Tom      Tuesday 3 
John     Tuesday 4
```

I need to put this into a dictionary within a dictionary so that the output is like this:

```
print(d)

d = {'Tom':{'Monday':5, 'Tuesday':3}, 'John': {'Monday':3, 'Tuesday':4'}..}
```

I tried doing `df.to_dict('dict')` but that is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Thank you.

Comment: Not very clear to me what the structure of your data frame is? Is it just one line like the one you pasted? What are the columns name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension with `GroupBy`:

```
res = {k: v.set_index('Day')['Hours_Worked'].to_dict() for k, v in df.groupby(['Employee'])}

# {'John': {'Monday': 2, 'Tuesday': 4}, 'Tom': {'Monday': 5, 'Tuesday': 3}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different solution also iterating over a `GroupBy`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = [
        ['Tom', 'Monday', 5],
        ['John', 'Monday', 2], 
        ['Tom', 'Tuesday', 3],
        ['John', 'Tuesday', 4]
    ],
    columns=['Employee', 'Day', 'Hours_Worked']
)

result = {
    employee: {row["Day"]: row["Hours_Worked"] for _, row in employee_data.iterrows()}
    for employee, employee_data in df.groupby("Employee")
}
```